# How to decompose characters of $D_5$ into characters of $C_5$

Tags: representation-theory, characters

Let $D_5$ be the dihedral group on $5$ vertices, and let $C_5$ a cyclic group of order $5$.

I have determined the character tables for both $D_5$ and $C_5$, and am now trying to decompose the restriction of each irreducible character of $D_5$ into irreducible characters of $C_5.$

My problem is that I'm not sure what is meant by this decomposition. 
Could anyone illuminate this problem?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** : I'll take $C_5 = \langle r \rangle \subset D_5$.

Any representation of $D_5$ restricts to a representation of $C_5$. This representation of $C_5$ will not stay irreducible anymore e.g if the dimension of your representation is $2$. If $V$ was your representation of $D_5$, then $\chi_{V|C_5}(r^k) = \chi_V(r^k)$ by definition. Since you already know the character table for $C_5$, you can now easily split $\chi_{V | C_5}$ into irreducible characters.

Comment: What happens to the one dimensional representations of $\chi_V$?

Comment: What does mean "representation of $\chi_V$" ? $V$ is a fixed representation.